# Aggregate features row-wise in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

i am trying to create features from sample that looks like this:

| index | user | product | sub_product | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | u1 | p1 | sp1 | NA |
| 1 | u1 | p1 | sp2 | NA |
| 2 | u1 | p1 | sp3 | CANCELED |
| 3 | u1 | p1 | sp4 | AVAIL |
| 4 | u2 | p3 | sp2 | AVAIL |
| 5 | u2 | p3 | sp3 | CANCELED |
| 6 | u2 | p3 | sp7 | NA |

first, i created dummies:

```
pd.get_dummies(x, columns = ['product', 'sub_product', 'status']
```

but i also need to group by row, to have 1 row by user, what is the best way to do it?

If i'll just group it:

```
pd.get_dummies(x, columns = ['product', 'sub_product', 'status'].groupby('user').max()
```

| user | product_p1 | product_p3 | sub_product_sp1 | sub_product_sp2 | sub_product_sp3 | sub_product_sp4 | sub_product_sp7 | status_AVAIL | status_CANCELED | status_NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| u2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

i will loose information, fo ex. that for u1 sp3 status is canceled. So it's looks like i have to create dummies for every column combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: You are basically looking for pivot:

```
out = (df.astype(str)
   .assign(value=1)
   .pivot_table(index=['user'], columns=['product','sub_product','status'],
                values='value', fill_value=0, aggfunc='max')
)

out.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in out.columns]
```

Comment: i tried, the same result as i already have with pd.get_dummies(x, columns = ['product', 'sub_product', 'status'].groupby('user').max() I think i need to have columns like sp3_status_AVAIL etc

Comment: @spynal I see, I thought that was what you expected. So what is your expected output? It seems like a `pivot` question.

Comment: I think i need also to have columns like sp3_status_AVAIL, sp3_status_NA etc, so basically all combination of existing columns.